# Formatting header and its border

Tags: html, css

Right now, I am working with this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1> nonono </h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

h1 {
    border: 2px solid;
    width: auto;
}
```

I'm hoping to have the border only around the text of the header and not spread over all the space width. The bottom border of the container should cross the "box" created by the text border in the middle.

Something like this:

[image: Example of the desired result.]

Does anyone have a hint of how to do this?

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/299u0k3o/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the code snippet below, this should work even if the <**h1**> tag has background color

```css
.container1 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  overflow-x: visible;
  height: 1.5em;

}

h1 {
  border: 1px solid #7788BB;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #3AF;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <h1> nonono </h1>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="container2">
  <hr/>      
  <h1> nonono </h1>
</div>
```

Also see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/299u0k3o/5/)

> NOTE: According to the [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model), [CSS Layer Stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index) and the [Stacking Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context),
>   you can never bring the border of **div.container1** on top of the
>   <**h1**> tag which is a descendant block of the container.

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange request, but I guess you can do it like this:

```css
.container {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    height: 42px;
}

h1 {
    border: 2px solid;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1> nonono </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your `<h1>` as it is you can also just wrap a `<span>` into it.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    <span>nonono</span>
  </h1>
</div>

h1 > span {
  border: 2px solid;
  width: auto;
}
```